# glsl texture2d speedup

Tags: opengl, glsl

im applying a 7x7 convolution filter, and I need it to be this big, but im experiencing a huge performance loss..

is there a faster way to accomplish this instead of a nested for loop? i.e:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    for(int p=0;p<7;p++) {
        k += texture2D(...);
    }
}
```

PS: im using `#version 140`

Comment: How have you determined that this code is responsible for your slowdown?  Is this from instruments or some other GPU profiling?  Accessing 49 entries doesn't seem like that big of a deal.  Perhaps unrolling the loop might help, but I think you might be looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: no its definitely this, no doubt about that..

Comment: aw yes.. i forgot to mention im runnin it on an 'old' GT330M (48 cores)

Comment: FYI: simply unrolling the loop I got 800% performance.. there must be some issue with the drivers..

Comment: ..and the s,t parameters were already precomputed, so the performance increase is just a consequence of the unrolling.. first time I stumble in something so weird (concerning GLSL of course)

Answer (score 2):

If your filter [is separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_design#Computational_complexity) then [separate it](https://web.archive.org/web/20120504092947/http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/).

That way you'll only have 7+7 = 14 lookups instead of 7*7 = 49.

Comment: That is awesome.  Filed under useful tidbits :)

Comment: unfortunately it is not separable :(